# SQL query calculate total number of occurrences with other conditions - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that tracks users login/logout activity. I'm trying to create a query that returns the total number of people that logged in for the day, and return one row for each day that is in the table. Here is an example of the table I am working with:

[image]

And here is the SQLFiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a1a5b/1/0

It has the Timestamp of when the action took place, the UserID of the person who performed the action, and the type of action itself. "LI" means "logged in", and "LO" means "logged out".

Here is an example of the preferred outcome of the query:

[image]

So there's a few things to note about this query:

- The query is supposed to only determine the number of people who "attended" for the day.
- It only counts ONCE if unique user has logged in for the day
- It does not matter if they logged in and logged out multiple times during the same day. It will still only count it ONCE for that user for that day.
- The Timestamp field is automatically converted into the day with zero hours/minutes/seconds.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to approach this query. Here's a couple of things I've tried but I have not been able to get close

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
AS
    TotalAttendance
FROM(
    SELECT
        [Timestamp],
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        Attendance
    WHERE
        Attendance.Timestamp>{ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'}
    AND
        Attendance.Action = 'LI'
    GROUP BY
        [UserID]
)
GROUP BY
    [Timestamp]
ORDER BY
    [Timestamp]
        ASC
```

This as well:

```
SELECT
    [Timestamp],
    COUNT(*) AS TotalAttendance
FROM
    Attendance
WHERE
    Attendance.Timestamp>{ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND
    Attendance.Action = 'LI'
GROUP BY
    [UserID],
    [Timestamp]
ORDER BY
    [Timestamp]
        ASC
```

And finally:

```
SELECT
    [Timestamp],
    COUNT(*) AS TotalAttendance
FROM
    Attendance
WHERE
    Attendance.Timestamp>{ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND
    Attendance.Action = 'LI'
GROUP BY
    [Timestamp],
    [AgentLogin]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    [Timestamp]
        ASC
```

Where am I going wrong here? I know that I have not yet addressed the timestamp conversion, but I figured the COUNT() part should be much easier than I'm making it. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can I get some insight on this please?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Cast("Timestamp" As date) As the_date
     , Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "Action" = 'LI' THEN UserID END) As attendance
FROM   Attendance
GROUP
    BY Cast("Timestamp" As date)
ORDER
    BY the_date
;
```

---

```
SELECT Cast("Timestamp" As date) As the_date
     , Count(DISTINCT UserID) As attendance
FROM   Attendance
WHERE  "Action" = 'LI'
GROUP
    BY Cast("Timestamp" As date)
ORDER
    BY the_date
;
```